# How can I combine these two arrays of arrays in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, delegates, combinations

I have two arrays that have the same length and the same format.I am looking for the shortest way to do something like this:

```
[[:todo],[],['text']].some_operation([[],[:low],[]])
->
[[:todo],[:low],['text']]
```

as I want the duplicates to be removed:

```
[[:todo],[],['text']].some_operation([[:todo],[:low],['text','more']])
->
[[:todo],[:low],['text','more']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the values in `a` and `b`, then

```
a.zip(b).map { |aa, bb| (aa + bb).uniq }
```

If you really want to put it onto the `Array` class, you can either monkey-patch it (not really recommended, especially for something this specific), or refine it (new, won't work in older versions).

Answer (score 0):

You could also do

```
a.each_with_index.map {|aa, i| aa | b[i] }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a.zip(b).map{|x|x.flatten.uniq}
```